# Matrix Multiplication Conceptual Question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**If I am multiplying an $m \times n$ matrix A with an $n \times p$ matrix B and I copy one wrong entry in A, then how many entries of the product AB must I check?**

I was thinking that the false entry of A will affect the values in the first row of B (meaning the number of columns of AB which is defined by the matrix B) so then the answer would be p.

Could anyone provide a more formal proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that 
$$ (AB)_{ij} = \sum_k A_{ik}B_{kj} $$
If you copied some $A_{ik}$ wrong, it may influence the value of all elements in the $i$-th row of $AB$, i. e. all $(AB)_{ij}$. As $AB$ has $p$ columns, as you write correctly, the answer is $p$.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I cannot think of any more formal proof.This goes by definition.Show that when you multiply one matrix by the other how the series goes.Imagine that the first element of matrix $A$ is wrong.Then show that by definition $A$ would have to be multiplied by the entire first column of matrix $B$.As this element is wrong,all the products of the first column would be wrong and as there are $p$ elements in the first column,$p$ is the correct number of things that would be wrong.

As @Martini said above a better way is to express the product in a more mathematical way as-$ (AB)_{ij} = \sum_k A_{ik}B_{kj} $

Answer (score 1):

In a system $AX=B$

Here is an example to show:

1 - Which elements of the result an element of A affects

2 - Which elements of the result an element of X affects

It may be interesting to note that a mistake in an element in A has different effect than a mistake in an element in B.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just rewriting that matrini said in matrix notation as I find it easier to see

$AB=\begin{bmatrix}
<r_1;c_1> & <r_1;c_2>& \dots & <r_1;c_p>\\
<r_2;c_1> & <r_2;c_2>& \dots & <r_2;c_p>\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
<r_m;c_1> & <r_m;c_2>& \dots & <r_m;c_p>
\end{bmatrix}$

where  $r_i$ is the $i^{th}$ row vector of $A$, and $c_j$ is the $j^{th}$ column vector of $B$.

So from this we can see that we will have to calculate all the entries for one row of $AB$, so $p$